# How to create a hidden dataset in the BigQuery WebUI whilst keeping datastudio connection possible?

Tags: python, dataset, pipeline, looker-studio

I am working on a data pipeline which eventually results in a table within a dataset in BigQuery. There are two conditions this dataset needs to meet: (1) it has to be able to connect to datastudio and (2) this dataset needs to be hidden in the WebUI of BigQUery. BigQuery documentation suggests the use of underscore in the naming of the dataset to hide it from the BigQuery WebUI. This works and I can control it through CLI. However, this also results in it being hidden from DataStudio which makes it not possible to connect to this dataset from DataStudio. I would like to know, if possible, how this (creating a dataset hidden from the BigQuery WebUI with connection possibility to DataStudio) could be achieved without having to create a new project.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [Creating datasets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets#create-dataset) BigQuery's documentation, datasets that begin with an underscore are hidden from the navigation pane; however, you can still query tables and views in these datasets even though they are not visible in the web UI.

Based on this, I have made some tests and found that an available workaround is to create the **Data Studio** connection by using the **Custom Query**; in this way, you can keep the dataset hidden from the Web UI and create the statements to access it based on your project needs.

[image]

Comment: My pleasure : )